# How generate different tokens from same string using GNU Flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I started to learn GNU Flex using [The Flex Manual Page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html). I try to use Flex to write a lexer which can tokenize documents and texts.
From this manpage I didn't get how a lexer can return different types of a token from same string.

For example, I have string `my_name@email.com`. I want to get the following tokens:

- `email` = `name@email.com`
- `name` = `my_name`
- `domain` = `email.com`

Is it possible using GNU Flex?

Update: My task is to tokenize a text string, which consists of various tokens (not only email addresses).

Comment: Those aren't all tokens. Tokens don't overlap, for example. Really, parsing email addresses is not a good fit for flex (although it can be done using start conditions).

Comment: @rici, thank you for your comment. Actually I'm going to parse not only email, but other token types too. Initial string can consist of various token types. I want to tokenize the string, and the main point is to overlap tokens.

Comment: Then you should probably find a different tool (and perhaps a different word: "tokens" are generally considered atomic units, so they don't overlap.)

Comment: @rici, thank you. I will look for a tool.